# How to work with Ports on Webpage?

Tags: sockets, vb6, localhost, port, html

There are many programs written VB6 that use TCP ports.
Some of them listening, server out web pages, for example: 192.168.1.2:5352, when I go to this page, I see a page that allows me to control the VB6 program, This means there are some options that the programmer put on the page)

I want to know how to do this with my program listening on a TCP port (6006) and how to put some commands on a page, for example a textbox and button, so that when I enter something into the textbox on the page, my program displays in a message box.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an HTTP server component that you can embed in your application.
This can then serve out standard HTML pages that post data back to your app with a normal POST or GET request.

You can either do this with plain TCP sockets via the [WinSock control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228119%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and manually parsing the HTTP requests, or by using a service built into windows like the [HTTP Server API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this is very difficult to use from native VB6.

Alternatively, you could loop at a plugin or CGI application with IIS or similar that communicates with your application via another method, maybe windows messages or named pipes.

Comment: What is the best way to do that ?  Please Learn me how to do it Thoroughly  . because i need it really !    Tnx  i want to use Winsock because its very easy . thank you to learn it .

Comment: @AmirrezA_Nasiri Writing a full HTTP server is not something I can explain on StackOverflow. There are plenty of Winsock tutorials around though.